# Apache Solr use entire string for search within collection

Tags: solr

I have managed to create a dataset using Apache Solr. I have also managed to make queries, such as in this example:

`content:(test1 OR test2) OR title: test2`

I would now like to search the dataset using an entire string, in similar fashion to searching on google. Is the correct way to approach this to keep using `or` tags on the title and content for each word within the query, or is there a better way to achieve this ? (I am not looking for exact matches, just the most relevant ones)

Comment: you can use dismax or edismax for your approach and can pass the phrases if you have with the boosting...check on https://solr.apache.org/guide/6_6/the-dismax-query-parser.html

Comment: If you post that an answer i'll mark it as correct, as that's what I was looking for! Thanks :)

Comment: Sure...Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dismax or edismax for your approach and can pass the phrases if you have with the boosting.

> The DisMax query parser is designed to process simple phrases (without
> complex syntax) entered by users and to search for individual terms
> across several fields using different weighting (boosts) based on the
> significance of each field. Additional options enable users to
> influence the score based on rules specific to each use case
> (independent of user input).

The detailed parameters are found on the solr page at [Solr Dismax](https://solr.apache.org/guide/6_6/the-dismax-query-parser.html)